# Error with drush clear-cache: Base table or view not found

Tags: 7, drush

There are similar questions out there, but I think this warrants a new thread.

I am getting the following error when running drush clear-cache all

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.cache_rules' doesn't exist: TRUNCATE {cache_rules} ;"

However, when I run the show tables command on the database, it clearly lists the cache_rules table.

Any ideas what is going on here and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps the table is corrupt? Might be worth running [mysqlcheck](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html).

Comment: Looks like your core_cache_rules table corrupted. You can drop this table and recreate again in the Database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to reset your cache_rules table, using a stable Drupal installation.

## Get cache_rules structure from clean database

You can get SQL text to drop/add the cache_rules table via the following steps:

1. Log in to phpMyAdmin on a functional Drupal site.
2. Click on the **columns** section under the **cache_rules table**
3. Click the **Export** button
4. Click '**Custom**' to show all options
5. Under 'Output' click '**view output as text**'
6. Under 'Format-specific options' choose '**structure**'
7. Under 'Object creation options' check '**Add DROP TABLE / TRIGGER statement**'
8. Copy the text displayed, or see below (sorry for the formatting)

Here is the SQL code to drop and add the table (thanks duckx!).

```
DROP TABLE cache_rules ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cache_rules` (
  `cid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique cache ID.',
  `data` longblob COMMENT 'A collection of data to cache.',
  `expire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or 0 for never.',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry was created.',
  `serialized` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0).',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Cache table for the rules engine to store configured items.';
```

## Drop/add the cache_rules table

Now navigate to the other database, using phpMyAdmin.

1. Make a full backup of the database
2. After the backup has been saved, click the **SQL** tab
3. Paste the text into the text box (removing any existing text)
4. Click '**Go**'

Comment: This appears the easiest way to handle the issue, so I am going to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code to run where it drops and adds the table back:

**REPLACE XX WITH YOUR OWN TABLE NAME....**

```
DROP TABLE XX_cache_rules ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `XX_cache_rules` (
  `cid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique cache ID.',
  `data` longblob COMMENT 'A collection of data to cache.',
  `expire` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry should expire, or 0 for never.',
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp indicating when the cache entry was created.',
  `serialized` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'A flag to indicate whether content is serialized (1) or not (0).',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`),
  KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Cache table for the rules engine to store configured items.';
```

Comment: Nicely done. Bit more complicated than what I used, but if it works it works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the two comments above, I ran mysqlcheck and confirmed the table was missing, even though the "show columns" command displayed it.

Then I went into /var/lib/mysql and removed all references to the table.

Logged into mysql and ran the drop table command for good measure.

And finally recreated the table. I referenced a working database to correctly model the table.

Comment: do you have the mysql command to recreate the table? im using the bash to do the drop and add tables